# How to find CPU load and application process load using Java ?

Tags: java, performance, cpu-usage

I would like to deploy video player web application in the Tomcat server and want to find out the CPU load for each and every user request to limit the number of users. I am able to find out the CPU load, however, am not sure how to calculate the CPU load for each and every request. Can anyone let me know if we have any open source API's or any other ideas would be greatly appreciated ?

I developed the web application using Adobe Flex and deployed in the Apache Tomcat Server.

Comment: Check out jtop demo located at JDK_INSTALL_PATH/demo/management/JTop. I think it's exactly what you need.

Comment: Another way to do this is to use   ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean().getSystemLoadAverage();

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

In a web application you can calculate the CPU usage for every request(thread) sustracting the total CPU thread time when entering the servlet to the total CPU thread time when leaving the servlet.

Something like this:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ...
{
  long iniCpuTime, endCpuTime, iniTs, endTs, threadId;

  ThreadMXBean mxBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();

  if (mxBean.isThreadCpuTimeSupported()) {
    threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
    iniTs = System.currentTimeMillis();
    iniCpuTime = mxBean.getThreadCpuTime(threadId);
  }

  // Business logic
  ....

  if (mxBean.isThreadCpuTimeSupported()) {
    endTs = System.currentTimeMillis();
    endCpuTime = mxBean.getThreadCpuTime(threadId);

    float cpu = (endCpuTime-iniCpuTime)/(float)((endTs-iniTs)*1000000);

    System.out.println("Request CPU usage (%): "+(cpu*100));
  }
}
```

But be aware, if the business logic executed in the servlet is not heavy enough, due to the uncertainty principle you can get weird results.